# Joomla v3 multiple PHP IF's in one statement

Tags: php, if-statement, joomla, joomla3.0

In Joomla v3, I want to do the following:

'countModules' the module with the following, to see if a module is assigned:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
```

But I also only want to show the module position on article pages only, not category blog pages using the below:

```
<?php if( JRequest::getVar( 'view' ) == 'article' ): ?>
```

How do I put both of the above IF's into 1 statement around the following so that the module position doesn't show & the div is removed only on the category blog page (but shows on article pages):

```
<section class="sidebar right-sidebar">
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="standard" />
</section>
```

Comment: `&&` between them? `if ($foo && $bar)`? This has nothing to do with Joomla - it's completely basic PHP?

Comment: Please don't use `JRequest` in Joomla 3.x as it's deprecated

Comment: Might be a Joomla thing... but the following doesn't work:  <?php if (($this->countModules('right')) && ( JRequest::getVar( 'view' ) == 'article' )): ?>

Comment: @user3544484 Then it's because one of those is `false` or falsy. Use `var_dump($this->countModules('right'), JRequest::getVar('view'))` to find out why.

Comment: yep... everything I expect to be there is there...

Comment: @user3544484 What does it output? I **promise** you that you're doing something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php
   $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
   $view = $jinput->get('view');

   if($view == 'article' && $this->countModules('right')) {
   ?>
      <section class="sidebar right-sidebar">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="standard" />
      </section>
   <?php
   }
?>
```

Also removed the old deprecated JRequest you were using and instead uses JApplication